# Мультиязычность ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Как лучше сделать многоязычность в приложении? На данный момент использую файлы ресурсов и там перевожу нужные мне слова на разные языки, но для длинного текста делать это неудобно. Я прочитал, что есть несколько способов реализации многоязычности:

1. С помощью файлов ресурсов.
2. Использование разных `View`.
3. Смешанный (1 и 2 сразу).

Я хочу использовать 3 вариант.

**Вопрос:** Как правильно выводить нужный `View`, если выбранный язык хранится в `Cookies`? И как быть с новостями, они у меня хранятся в БД на английском. Надо делать другую таблицу для новостей на русском?

Answer (score -1):

В asp.net mvc 5 настроить зависимость view от контекста запроса (в том числе и от cookie) можно через DisplayModeProvider в файле Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterLanguageDisplayModeProvider("Ru");
        RegisterLanguageDisplayModeProvider("En");

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    protected void RegisterLanguageDisplayModeProvider(string languageName)
    {
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(1, new DefaultDisplayMode(languageName)
        {
            ContextCondition = context => context.Request.Cookies["Language"] != null && context.Request.Cookies["Language"].Value.ToString() == languageName
        });
    }
```

Теперь в названиях разных версий view можно указывать Ru.ViewName.cshtml En.ViewName.cshtml. Это же работает и для layout-ов

По поводу дизайна базы данных есть хорошая [статья](http://www.apphp.com/tutorials/index.php?page=multilanguage-database-design-in-mysql). Там используется MySql, но подходы спокойно применяются и для MsSql